# Pyspark dataframe sum variable up to the current row's month

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe that looks as follows:

```
date, loan
1.1.2020, 0
1.2.2020, 0
1.3.2020, 0
1.4.2020, 10000
1.5.2020, 200
1.6.2020, 0
```

I would like to have the fact that they took out a loan in month 4 to reflect on the other later months as well. So the resulting dataframe would be:

```
date, loan
1.1.2020, 0
1.2.2020, 0
1.3.2020, 0
1.4.2020, 10000
1.5.2020, 10200
1.6.2020, 10200
```

Is there any simple way to do this in pyspark? Thanks.

Comment: With a modification, yes! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Ehrendil - do you want to calculate running total ..

```
select date,loan,
sum(loan) over(order by date row between unbounded preceding and current row) as running_total from table
```